# How to configure akka-http to return HTTP 503 in case of request timeouts

Tags: scala, http, akka, akka-stream

I have a web application implemented using akka-http (version 1.0). It works fine with a small number (less than 40) of concurrent users. However when number of users reaches 40 I consistently see the following errors in the logs:

> 'Publisher (akka.stream.impl.MultiStreamOutputProcessor$SubstreamOutput@6d094473) you are trying to subscribe to has been shut-down because exceeding it's subscription-timeout.

The returned response is HTTP 500 Internal server error.

What configuration property is used to control this timeout?

Is it possible to configure akka-http to return HTTP 503 automatically in case of timeouts?

Comment: `subscription-timeout` can be configured via `akka.stream.materializer.subscription-timeout` setting. Take a look on docs http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/stream-configuration.html

Comment: I created a ticket to track this: https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/18274