# Akka Http non-responsive

Tags: scala, http, akka, akka-stream

I had a responsive Akka Http app, did some changes, then got these messages:

```
14:55:56.128 INFO  bootstrap.akka.HttpActor - Accepted new connection from /127.0.0.1:55192 
14:56:23.938 INFO  bootstrap.akka.HttpActor - Accepted new connection from /127.0.0.1:55193 
14:56:26.684 ERROR akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl - Internal server error, sending 500 response 
akka.stream.impl.io.TcpStreamActor$$anonfun$handleSubscriptionTimeout$1$$anon$1: Publisher was not attached to upstream within deadline (5000) ms
14:56:26.684 ERROR akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl - Internal server error, sending 500 response 
akka.stream.impl.io.TcpStreamActor$$anonfun$handleSubscriptionTimeout$1$$anon$1: Publisher was not attached to upstream within deadline (5000) ms
```

I cannot figure out what they mean. They are not mentioned in the docs and no Google hits. Could anyone share some insight?

```
akka.version=2.3.12
akka.stream.version=1.0
scala.version=2.11.6
jdk.version=1.8.0_60
```

Comment: You're probably going to have to share some code in order for a better diagnosis.

Comment: @cmbaxter I wish I could. The app has gotten quite big, and it's difficult to pinpoint the exact parts to share. The problem is intermittent. It seems to occur with rapid stop/start of the app but it's hard to tell. Could be lingering tcp connections in time_wait state or something.

Comment: This may be related to another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32085345/how-to-configure-akka-http-to-return-http-503-in-case-of-request-timeouts